# Only one XMLElementRef marshalled

Tags: java, jaxb, moxy

I have the following class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "entity")
public class Entity {

    @XmlElementRef
    protected AtomLink first;
    @XmlElementRef
    protected AtomLink second;

    public Entity() {
    }

    public Entity(AtomLink first, AtomLink second) {
        this.first = first;
    this.second = second;
    }
}
```

This is my test code:

```
Entity entity = new Entity(new AtomLink("first", "http://test/first"), new AtomLink("second", "http://test/second"));
JAXBContext context;
try {
    context = JAXBContextFactory.createContext(new Class[] { Entity.class } , null);
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.marshal(entity, System.out);
} catch (JAXBException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The output with MOXy is wrong because the first link is missing:

```
<entity xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <atom:link rel="second" href="http://test/second"/>
</entity>
```

The output with Java JAXB RI is correct:

```
<entity xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <atom:link rel="first" href="http://test/first"/>
    <atom:link rel="second" href="http://test/second"/>
</entity>
```

Is it a bug in MOXy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

> Is it a bug in MOXy?

No, not really.  The problem is that it is not valid to have two properties of the same type both annotated with `@XmlElementRef`. If you used the JAXB RI to unmarshal:

```xml
<entity xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <atom:link rel="first" href="http://test/first"/>
    <atom:link rel="second" href="http://test/second"/>
</entity>
```

And marshal it back out then just like MOXy you will get:

```xml
<entity xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <atom:link rel="second" href="http://test/second"/>
</entity>
```

---

**WORKAROUND - ANY JAXB (JSR-222) IMPLEMENTATION**

In JAXB repeating elements should be represented in a collection property:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Entity {

    @XmlElementRef
    protected List<AtomLink> first;

    public Entity() {
    }

}
```

---

**USING MOXy's `@XmlPath`**

Below is an example of how you can leverage MOXy's `@XmlPath` extension to support this use case.

***package-info***

Assuming you had the following namespace information specified in your `@XmlSchema` annotation.

```
@XmlSchema(
    xmlns={
       @XmlNs(prefix="atom", namespaceURI="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
    }
)
package forum14998000;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

***Entity***

Then you can use `@XmlPath` to map a field to an element with a specific attribute value.  Since since we are matching on more than the elements name/URI we won't hit the original problem.

```
package forum14998000;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement(name = "entity")
public class Entity {

    @XmlPath("atom:link[@rel='first']")
    protected AtomLink first;

    @XmlPath("atom:link[@rel='second']")
    protected AtomLink second;

    public Entity() {
    }

    public Entity(AtomLink first, AtomLink second) {
        this.first = first;
    this.second = second;
    }

}
```

***AtomLink***

Now that the `rel` attribute is covered in the `@XmlPath` annotation we do not include it as a field in the `AtomLink` class.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom", name="link")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class AtomLink {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String href;

}
```

***For More Information***

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html